# MigraDoc - Setting Cell Colour from Hex

Tags: c#, colors, migradoc

Have a `HEX` colour code string in the database (`"#ADD8E6"`) and I want to use this to change the background colour of a `MigraDoc` cell. I have found `Color.Parse()` function, however it isn't changing the colour of my cell. I have had to do the following:

```
string colourHex = (database.HexCode).Replace("#", "0x");
var colourObject = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Color.Parse(colourHex);

Cell.Shading.Color = colourObject;
```

I know that the `Cell.Shading.Color` is correct because if I apply `Cell.Shading.Color = Colors.AliceBlue` then the cell does change colour as expected. I understand the `Color.Parse` requires the `HEX` code to start with `0x` rather than `#`. I tried using the `#` and it failed... At least with what I have got it is rendering... just not with my colour.

Comment: I think your code is correct, so something you are assuming must be wrong.

Comment: I think the question is on-topic and provides enough information - at least to those familiar with MigraDoc. Several senseless question never got closed (my close votes expired).

Comment: Your question inspired me to enhance the `Color.Parse` method (see my answer). Thanks for asking your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to replace "#" with "0xff" to get what you want.

With your short numbers (three components only) the alpha channel will always be 0 and the colour will be completely transparent. With `0xff` followed by six hex digits for the RGB colours you get a colour with full opacity.

**Update:** With the current version of MigraDoc 1.50 (beta 5b or later) you can also use the hash sign followed by 3, 6, or 8 hex digits. 8 digits include the alpha channel, with 3 or 6 digits an alpha setting of FF is used.
With the new version, the code `#ADD8E6` will have the expected effect.
Nothing has changed when the `0x` prefix is used.

Comment: Amazing - many thanks for that! Worked perfectly...! Not sure why this is considered 'Off-Topic'??